# How to access a column metadata using index in different Parquet files

Tags: python, parquet

I am trying to iterate through many parquet files that don't have the same number of columns, but they have a column in commun that I am interested in. Let's say that the column is called 'A'

I want to get the max value of column 'A' for each parquet file knowing that the index of 'A' is changing accroding to total number of columns in the files.

I am  using its index as in this expression the column in question has index 6

```
parquet_file.metadata.row_group(0).column(6).statistics.max
```

knowing that column() here only accepts integers , how can I relate my column to its index in each parquet file in order to create a for loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: note some writers truncate statistics when writing out strings so the value should be considered be an upperbound and not necessarily a true max

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [path_in_schema](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ColumnChunkMetaData.html#pyarrow.parquet.ColumnChunkMetaData.path_in_schema) attribute to match against the attribute name you want (so you need to iterate over column indexes and match on the underlying attribute).

I believe the underlying c++ schema object has a mapping from name to schema, so it might pay to file a feature request to accept name as an index as well.